# Crash in prepareForSegue()

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am trying to transfer the score of a game over to a viewController once time has run out. I currently have this bit of code in one viewController.

```
var score = 0
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toResults" {
            var svc = segue.destinationViewController as! Results
            svc.resultsScore == (score)
        }
    }
```

In my second view controller I have this code:

```
var resultsScore: Int!

@IBOutlet weak var finalScore: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    finalScore.text = "\(resultsScore)"

}
```

In the first viewController while trying to pass the score to resultsScore in the Results viewController it crashes at this line with this error code.

```
svc.resultsScore == (score)
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Why would this be happening? I have passed data from one VC to another before and this has not happened. Is this unsafe to pass it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
svc.resultsScore == (score)
```

== is the comparison operator.

assign it using 1 equal sign, =

```
svc.resultsScore = (score)
```

Comment: Ugh, rookie mistake and waste of a question. Thank you.